# Connecting key accelerators in Gtk+ (gtkmm)

Tags: c++, gtk, keyboard-shortcuts, gtkmm

I've been writing a Gtk+ application using gtkmm, and I'm trying to add a global keyboard shortcut which calls a callback. Unfortunately, the connect() method of Gtk::AccelGroup isn't available in gtkmm, apparently intentionally because you can make the connections using ActionGroups...

Anyway, I have the following code:

```
actions_= Gtk::ActionGroup::create();
actions_->set_accel_group(Gtk::AccelGroup::create());

actions_->add(
    Gtk::Action::create("new"), Gtk::AccelKey("<control>n"),
    sigc::mem_fun(this, &Window::new_buffer_thing)
);

_gtk_window().add_accel_group(actions_->get_accel_group());
```

Which compiles and runs without warning, but the keyboard shortcut does nothing. I've been fiddling with this for hours, so any help or direction would be appreciated!

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Why wouldn't the accelerator work?

Comment: I tried this and also couldn't get it to do anything - but then I don't know whether this was  the recommended way to do it, and I just pasted it wholesale, so if there _is_ anything missing, I wouldn't know what it is! The real reason for this comment is that, since this is quite high on Google for things like _GTKmm keyboard shortcuts, for readers_ - it looks like `ActionGroup` is deprecated as of GTKmm 3.10, and quick searches indicate it's been replaced by similarly named classes in the recent `Gio` (glibmm) namespace. Maybe you'll have more luck there.

Answer (score 1):

a bit late to answer this, but I've been working at this same problem today, even if in a different environment: python, gtk2.

as far as I understand from a little experimenting with [this tutorial](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/actions.py), actions won't be active unless associated to a toolbox or a menubar. too bad, just do that, pack the toolbar into a VBox, and make it invisible, something like this:

```
actiongroup = gtk.ActionGroup('window-clip-actions')
accelgroup = gtk.AccelGroup()
fake_toolbar = gtk.Toolbar()
view.get_window().add_accel_group(accelgroup)
view.get_window().get_content_area().pack_start(fake_toolbar)
for shortcut, cb in (('<ctrl><shift>c', self.on_window_clip_copy),
                     ('<ctrl><shift>v', self.on_window_clip_paste)):
    action = gtk.Action(shortcut, shortcut, 'clip-action', None)
    actiongroup.add_action_with_accel(action, shortcut)
    action.connect("activate", cb)
    action.set_accel_group(accelgroup)
    action.connect_accelerator()
    toolitem = action.create_tool_item()
    fake_toolbar.insert(toolitem, -1)
fake_toolbar.set_visible(False)
```

it would be interesting to know if the same approach would help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

After reading mariotomo's answer, here's my implementation of hidden menubar for gtkmm3.

Shortcut key accelerator works for hidden menubar :)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

using Gtk::Application;
using Gtk::Box;
using Gtk::Builder;

using Gio::SimpleActionGroup;

using std::cout;

class ExampleWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    ExampleWindow(const Glib::RefPtr<Application>& app);

private:
    void on_action_file_new();
    // for hidden menubar
    void on_action_secret();

    Box box1;
    Box box2;

    Glib::RefPtr<Builder>           builder;
    Glib::RefPtr<SimpleActionGroup> actiongroup;
};

ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow(const Glib::RefPtr<Application>& app)
    : box1(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL)
    , box2(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL)
{
    set_title("Menubar test");
    set_default_size(400, 200);

    add(box1);

    box1.add(box2);

    //Define the actions:
    actiongroup = Gio::SimpleActionGroup::create();

    actiongroup->add_action("new"   , sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_action_file_new));
    actiongroup->add_action("secret", sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_action_secret));

    insert_action_group("example"       , actiongroup);
    insert_action_group("example-hidden", actiongroup);

    builder = Gtk::Builder::create();

    app->set_accel_for_action("example.new"          , "<Primary>n");
    app->set_accel_for_action("example-hidden.secret", "<Primary>m");

    const char *visible_ui_info =
        "<interface>"
        "  <menu id='visible-menubar'>"
        "    <submenu>"
        "      <attribute name='label' translatable='yes'>_File</attribute>"
        "      <section>"
        "        <item>"
        "          <attribute name='label' translatable='yes'>_New</attribute>"
        "          <attribute name='action'>example.new</attribute>"
        "          <attribute name='accel'>&lt;Primary&gt;n</attribute>"
        "        </item>"
        "      </section>"
        "    </submenu>"
        "  </menu>"
        "</interface>";
    
    const char *hidden_ui_info = 
        "<interface>"
        "  <menu id='hidden-menubar'>"
        "    <submenu>"
        "      <attribute name='label' translatable='yes'>_Secret</attribute>"
        "      <section>"
        "        <item>"
        "          <attribute name='label' translatable='yes'>_Key</attribute>"
        "          <attribute name='action'>example-hidden.secret</attribute>"
        "          <attribute name='accel'>&lt;Primary&gt;m</attribute>"
        "        </item>"
        "      </section>"
        "    </submenu>"
        "  </menu>"
        "</interface>";

    builder->add_from_string(visible_ui_info);
    builder->add_from_string(hidden_ui_info);

    // Get the visible menubar:
    auto object1  = builder->get_object("visible-menubar");
    auto gmenu1   = Glib::RefPtr<Gio::Menu>::cast_dynamic(object1);
    auto menubar1 = Gtk::make_managed<Gtk::MenuBar>(gmenu1);
    box1.pack_start(*menubar1, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

    // Get the hidden menubar
    auto object2  = builder->get_object("hidden-menubar");
    auto gmenu2   = Glib::RefPtr<Gio::Menu>::cast_dynamic(object2);
    auto menubar2 = Gtk::make_managed<Gtk::MenuBar>(gmenu2);
    box2.pack_start(*menubar2, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

    show_all_children();
    box2.hide();
}

void ExampleWindow::on_action_file_new()
{
    cout << "New menu item was selected.\n";
}

void ExampleWindow::on_action_secret()
{
    cout << "Secret menu item was selected.\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto app = Application::create("org.gtkmm.example");

    ExampleWindow window(app);

    return app->run(window);
}
```